# Code for push and pop in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to implement the `push` and `pop` functionality of perl functions by writing the code using array and top of the array.
For example: `pop` will pop out the last element. But how to do it by getting the last value of the array?

I have written the below code, but seems its not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
$in = $1; 
sub push { 
    my $top = 0; 
    @stack=("a","b","c"); 
    my $max = 20; 
    print "Push: @stack."; 
    if($top = $max - 1) { 
        print "Overflow"; 
    } 
    else { 
        $stack[$top] = $in; 
        $top = $top + 1; 
        print "After Push: @stack."; 
    } 
    print "Before Pop: @stack."; 
    my $new=$stack[$top]; 
    $top = $top - 1; 
    print "Popped item: $new."; 
    print "After Pop: @stack."; 
}
```

Comment: [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html), [pop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html)

Comment: Does it give the result you want? Then it is "correct". If you are looking for a code review, you are on the wrong site and might want to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? I can't imagine any other reason you'd want to re-implement built-in functions. If it is, that's fine, but it helps to explain that in your question so people answering can adjust their answers appropriately.

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: You should know that this is incorrect: `if($top = $max - 1)`. You are using assignment operator `=` when you (probably) should use numeric equality operator `==`. It will still appear to work, if you do not have `warnings` enabled, because Perl without warnings will gladly allow you to shoot yourself in the foot. Also, `$1` refers to capture group in a regex, and I assume you want to access the arguments passed to the program. In which case you should use the `@ARGV` array.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you are trying to do, so we can't tell you if you are doing it. But it seems what you wrote could be written more clearly using [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) and [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html).

```
my $stack_size = 20;
my @stack;

sub push_onto_stack {
   my ($item) = @_;
   die "Overflow\n" if @stack > $stack_size;
   push @stack, $item;   
}

sub pop_from_stack {
   die "Stack empty\n" if !@stack;
   return pop @stack;
}
```

If this was an assignment that requires avoid the use of `push` and `pop`, then you could use

```
$stack[@stack] = $item;               # push @stack, $item
```

and

```
my $item = $stack[-1];  --$#stack;    # my $item = pop @stack;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written the code as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

our @stack=("this","is","a","basic","example");
our $top = $#stack;

sub push_test {
    my $max = 7;
    print "\nCurrent Stack is: @stack\n";
    if($top == $max - 1)
    {
            print "\nScript Overflown. Testing others.\n";
    }
    else
    {
            $stack[@stack] = $in;
            $top+=1;
            print "After Push Stack is: @stack\n";
    }
}

sub pop_test {
    print "\nBefore Pop Stack is: @stack.\n";
    my $new = $stack[-1];
    --$#stack;
    print "Poped item is: $new.\n";
    print "After Pop Stack is: @stack\n";
}

sub peek_test {
    my $peek = $stack[0];
    print "\nPeek element is: $peek\n";
}

sub empty_test {
    print "\nTop value: $top.\n";
    if ($top == -1)
    {
    print "Array is empty.\n";
    }
    else
    {
    print "Array is not empty.\n";
    }
}

foreach $i (@ARGV){
    $in=$i;
    print "\nTESTING SCRIPT";
    print "\nTest: Push";
    push_test($in);
}
    print "\nTest: Pop";
    pop_test();
    print "\nTest: Peek";
    peek_test();
    print "\nTest: Is_empty";
    empty_test();
exit;
```